# Python: Tkinter access variable from another module

Tags: python, tkinter

Somewhere in my code I import this module:

```
import sModule as s
```

And initialize my main Tkinter window like this:

```
base = tk.Tk()

mw = MainWindow(base).grid()
s.parent = sys.modules[__name__]

base.mainloop()
```

And `MainWindow` class is something like this:

```
class MainWindow(tk.Frame): 
  def __init__(self, parent):
    self.info1 = tk.StringVar()
    self.info2 = tk.StringVar()
```

What I'm trying to do is accessing `info1` and `info2` in `sModule` like this:

```
parent.mw.info1.set(str1)
```

And I'm getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'info1'

Which part is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace following line:

```
mw = MainWindow(base).grid()
```

with:

```
mw = MainWindow(base)
mv.grid()
```

Why? `grid()` does not return anything; implicitly return `None`.